# How to make a multiple toggle form with one form id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a comment form in Django, I added a little javascript functionality to it by showing it when user clicks on the reply button.But the problem I am having is that every comment will be loaded will be having one same id so it doesn't make the toggle functionality available after the comments first.

Here's my html code

```
                                        {% for comment in comments %}
                                    <ul class="comment-list">
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="single-comment">
                                                <div class="comment-avatar">
                                                    <img src="/static/img/others/comment-2.jpg" alt="comment">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="comment-info">
                                                    <div class="comment-meta">
                                                        <p class="comment-author"><a href="#">{{ comment.name }} </a></p>
                                                        <span class="comment-date">{{ comment.created }}</span>
                                                        <button type="button" class="reply" id="reply">Reply</button>
                                                        <a href="{% url 'blog:delete' comment.id%}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="comment-content">
                                                        <p>{{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="reply-comment"></div>

                                           <form action="." method="post" id="form1">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                <!-- Hidden input for parent comment.id -->
                                                <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                                                <div class="form__group mb--30 mb-sm--20">
                                                    <div class="form-row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-sm--20">
                                                            <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="comment_name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                            {{form.name}}
                                                        </div>  
                                                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-sm--20">
                                                            <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="comment_email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                            {{form.email}}
                                                        </div> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form__group mb--30 mb-sm--20">
                                                    <div class="form-row">
                                                        <div class="col-12">
                                                            <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="review">Your Review<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                            {{form.body}}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form__group">
                                                    <div class="form-row">
                                                        <div class="col-12">
                                                            <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-style-1 btn-submit mb-4" style="margin-top: -1rem;">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>



                                            <ul class="children">
                                            {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="single-comment">
                                                        <div class="comment-avatar">
                                                            <img src="/static/img/others/comment-2.jpg" alt="comment">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="comment-info">
                                                            <div class="comment-meta">
                                                                <p class="comment-author"><a href="#">Reply to {{comment.name}} by @{{ reply.name }} </a></p>
                                                                <span class="comment-date">{{ reply.created }}</span>

                                                                <button  id="reply-child" name="reply-child" class="reply">Reply</button>
                                                                <a href="{% url 'blog:delete' reply.id%}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="comment-content">
                                                                <p>{{ reply.body }}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </li>
                                            </ul> 

                                                <form action="." method="post" id="form2">
                                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                                    <!-- Hidden input for parent comment.id -->
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ reply.id }}">
                                                    <div class="form__group mb--30 mb-sm--20">
                                                        <div class="form-row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-sm--20">
                                                                <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="comment_name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                                {{form.name}}
                                                            </div>  
                                                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-sm--20">
                                                                <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="comment_email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                                {{form.email}}
                                                            </div> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form__group mb--30 mb-sm--20">
                                                        <div class="form-row">
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <label class="form__label form__label--3" for="review">Your Review<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                                {{form.body}}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form__group">
                                                        <div class="form-row">
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-style-1 btn-submit mb-4" style="margin-top: -1rem;">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>





                                            {% for c_reply in reply.replies.all %}
                                                <li style="margin-left: 3rem;">
                                                    <div class="single-comment">
                                                        <div class="comment-avatar">
                                                            <img src="/static/img/others/comment-2.jpg" alt="comment">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="comment-info">
                                                            <div class="comment-meta">
                                                                <p class="comment-author"><a href="#">
                                                                Reply to {{reply.name}} by  @{{ c_reply.name }} </a></p>
                                                                <span class="comment-date">{{ c_reply.created }}</span>


                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="comment-content">
                                                                <p>{{ c_reply.body }}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </li>

                                                {% endfor %}


                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>

                                        {% empty %}
                                        <h4>There are no comments yet.</h4>
                                        {% endfor %}
```

Here's my tiny little JavaScript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").hide();
  $("#reply").click(function() {
    $("#form1").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ids should be unique

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Class Selector `('.class')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to attach event handler with *reply* element and then use various DOM traversal methods i.e. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target the desired `<FORM>` element

```
//Hide All Forms
$("form").hide();

//Use Class selector to attach event handler
$(".reply").click(function() {
    $(this) //Current element which invoked the event handler
     .closest('li') // First Ancestor LI element
     .children('form') //Immediate Child of LI element
     .toggle();
});
```

Comment: It's just making the toggle for the parent comment.ACtually I have multiple singl-comment classes .I have updated the code .Please check.

Comment: @UbaidParvaiz, Use `$(this).closest('li').children('form').toggle();`

Comment: after  using children I get another problem and that is then all open at the same time .If you click at one reply every form gets toggled down

Answer (score 0):

With **vanilla javascript**:

```
const forms = [...document.querySelectorAll('form')];
forms.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hide'));

/**
Given your html the nextSibling of a .single-comment is always a form.
*/
const toggleNextForm = replyEl => {
  replyEl.closest('.single-comment').nextSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
};

const replies = [...document.querySelectorAll('.reply')];
replies.forEach(el => el.onclick = toggleNextForm);
```

*Please switch the **hide class** for whatever **CSS class** is used in your implementation.*